# Multiple Sound Buttons in Android: Starting, Stopping and Looping sounds through buttons

Tags: android, button, audio

I'm new to Android programming and I am having a couple issues. I'm trying to make an app that has three buttons that all play different short sounds. I would like for the sounds to not overlap each other, so when I press one button, the sound from another stops. Here is my code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

.

```
package com.example.soundbutton;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      final MediaPlayer s1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.trumpet);
      final MediaPlayer s2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sy04);
      final MediaPlayer s3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.machine);

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                s2.stop();
                s3.stop();

                try {
                    s1.prepare();
                    s1.seekTo(0);
                    s1.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        b2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                s1.stop();
                s3.stop();

                try {
                    s2.prepare();
                    s2.seekTo(0);
                    s2.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

       Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        b3.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                s2.stop();
                s1.stop();

                try {
                    s3.prepare();
                    s3.seekTo(0);
                    s3.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    }
```

I have searched quite a bit on this and answers from similar issues have not worked for me. So far the app will not play the first button I press at all, but then allow you to play the other buttons. After a few clicks, all the buttons seize to work. I have heard SoundPool is ideal for short sounds but I couldn't find any sample code for what I'm trying to do. Anyway, I know there has to be a fix for this and I apologize if this is a trivial question. I would also appreciate info on how to loop the sounds for each button and still have the sounds from each button not overlap. Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stopping other `MediaPlayer` objects without knowing if they are even playing:
This part:

```
s2.stop();
s3.stop();
```

You need to wrap these in a if loop to make sure they are playing before you stop them.

```
if(s2.isPlaying() || s2.isLooping()) {
  s2.stop();
  }
if(s3.isPlaying() || s3.isLooping()) {
  s3.stop();
  }
```

Change accordingly in other cases. Also take a look at this doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.view.SurfaceHolder%29). It says when a `MediaPlayer` object is created using `MediaPlayer.create`, then it will have invoked the `prepare()` call already so you dont need to call `prepare()` again before starting.

Comment: I have edited my code. I removed the  and prepare call, IO Exception, and try/catch. So it looks like this now    if(s2.isPlaying() || s2.isLooping()){s2.stop();
}
if(s3.isPlaying() || s3.isLooping()){
s3.stop();

s1.start();
}
Now all the buttons will play sound, but when one is clicked and it stops the sound of another button. The previous button will not play after it is clicked on again.